# Scan QR code without using google play services

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode

I have an android app which on local WiFi and doesn't require an internet connection so I am looking for a solution which can scan QR codes without requiring Google Play Services as no internet connection is there so I do not want to update Google Play Services. Currently, I am doing it by using Google Vision API but somehow(if possible) I want to remove this dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the link for the same :

[QR Code Reader without requiring google play services](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView)